# why structure members are not aligning according to the largest data member in the structure?

Tags: c

I read that in structure members are aligned according to the largest data member in the structure. But it seems to be not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct abc
{
    char a[10];
    int b;
    float f;
    double d;
    char c;
};

main()
{
    printf("size : %d", sizeof(struct abc));
    printf("size of double : %d", sizeof(double));
}
```

Structure size is printing as 32 bytes. But I expected it to print 40 as a(10) + 2 padding bytes + b(4) + f(4) + 4 padding bytes + d(8) + c(1) + 7 padding bytes. Can any one please let me know why this is not working as expected?

Comment: I tried it , its giving 40. Recompile your code and check again.

Comment: I tried many times. But it is giving 32 only. Does it depend on compiler?

Comment: kadina, it very much depends on the compiler. I get a similar output for 32-bit Debian as per the test program given in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items are aligned *as required by the implementation.* This is something *allowed* by the standard, not *mandated.* See, for example, `C11 6.2.8 Alignment of objects` which states how alignments work, but gives no requirement as to what alignments exist for specific objects. All it has to say, in essence, is (my bold):

> An alignment is an **implementation-defined** integer value representing the number of bytes between  successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated.

It may be, for example, that 8-byte doubles don't require 8-byte alignment.  Best bet is to create a variable and get the address of each field with something like:

```
printf("%p\n", &(var.d));
```

A complete program on my Debian install shows you what the offsets and sizes are:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct {
    char   a[10];
    int    b;
    float  c;
    double d;
    char   e;
} xyzzy;

#define describe(fld) \
    printf ("    " #fld ": %2zd @ %2zd (%2zd)\n", \
    sizeof (xyzzy.fld), \
    (((char *)(&(xyzzy.fld))) - ((char *)(&(xyzzy)))), \
    _Alignof (xyzzy.fld))

int main (void) {
    describe (a);
    describe (b);
    describe (c);
    describe (d);
    describe (e);
    puts("=====");
    printf("total: %2zd @  0 (%2zd)\n", sizeof (xyzzy), _Alignof (xyzzy));
    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives me:

```
    a: 10 @  0 ( 1)
    b:  4 @ 12 ( 4)
    c:  4 @ 16 ( 4)
    d:  8 @ 20 ( 4)
    e:  1 @ 28 ( 1)
=====
total: 32 @  0 ( 4)
```

which is basically the same as what *you're* seeing, a total size of 32.

And, in fact, you can see that the alignment requirement for `double d` is *not* a multiple of its size - that would put it at `24` rather than `20`. The number inside the parentheses is the alignment requirement, which is `4` for the `double`.

Answer (score 3):

C structures are aligned according to the *most strictly aligned* data member, which may or may not be the largest member. (In your example, the largest member is `char a[10]`, whose size is 10 but whose alignment is only 1.)

The precise alignment constraints are *implementation-dependent*; the only requirement provided by the standard is that all alignments are powers of 2.

The alignment of an object does not need to be the same as its size. On 32-bit Intel platforms running Posix(-like) systems, for example, no primitive type has an alignment of more than four bytes, including eight-byte doubles and 10-byte long doubles (if implemented by the C compiler). But other platform ABIs require 8 byte-aligned doubles, which makes the size of `long doubles` 16 bytes instead of 12 bytes (although in all cases, the hardware uses only 80 bits.)

A large number of platform and CPU-dependent details are contained in documents called "Application Binary Interface" (ABI) specifications. These specifications are not generally standards, in the sense that they are not sanctified by international standards bodies, but they are nonetheless generally respected in order to allow interoperability between different compilers, linkers, and system libraries. You can find a listing of some of these specifications relevant to Linux implementations on the [Linux Foundation's Referenced Specifications page](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/). In particular, the document which specifies the alignment of fundamental types on i386 hardware is the ["System V Application Binary Interface Intel386 Architecture Processor Supplement, Fourth Edition"](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/abi386-4.pdf) (a 377-page PDF file, which needs to be read in conjunction with the System V Application Binary Interface base document, another 271 pages.) You'll find the chart on page 28.